# How to add SSH key to a running IBM virtual server?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

During creating Virtual server on IBM cloud you are allowed to select one or more SSH key from ssh keys you have added. But I can not find a way to add any new ssh key after instance creation.

So how can I attach ssh key to running IBM Virtual server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add another SSH key to your virtual server, you have to

1. log in to that machine and
2. add the key information to the file **~/.ssh/authorized_keys file**

When you take a look into that file, you should see the key(s) configured during instance creation.

Comment: The problem is the user who created the instance is no longer reachable so I wanted to add my ssh key but I'm not able to ssh to the current running Instances

Comment: My answer is correct. Please mark it as answered. Your problem is similar to the admin leaving the company without handing over important passwords.